# CVD $\rm MoS_2$ always get many particles/stuff on the surface, what is problem?

Tags: material-science, physical-chemistry

The  $\rm MoO_3$ and  $\rm SiO_2$ substrate is placed in the center of furnace and sulfur boat is in the upstream out of the furnace. In a general growth:

- ~2mg MoO3 and ~200mg Sulfur is used (PTAS as promoter)
- Gas: Ar – 80 sccm
- Growth time: 10 min
- growth temp: 650C

Bellow are the images I got (both AFM and optical images), many stuff/particles on the MoS2 surface.

What is problem and how should I change for set up/receipt? I have tried with different growth time (1,4,7,10 min), increase distance between MoO3 source and SiO2 substrate, change MoO3 amount (1mg, 5mg) but still I get the same results.

[image]

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Consider migrating to Chemistry.